# How to use sharedpreference from its class?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I store a value in Activity class from a spinner ,  is it possible  to get the value without context ?

---

*SharedPreference.class*

```
 public static int getPreferencedCurrency(){

        SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(Constants.SHARED_PREFERENCES_NAME,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        return prefs.getInt(Constants.CURRENCY_PREFERRED,0);

    }
```

Error on getSharedPreferences

Comment: Post your code of what you have tried so far.

Comment: `Error on getSharedPreferences` pls post the error/[logcat](https://politecuriosity.files.wordpress.com/2013/05/logcat.jpg) if any

Comment: can try this way `PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext()).getInt(key, defValue);`

Answer (score 0):

What exactly do you mean by storing a value in the SP class? What exactly do you need to do with that value?

You can easily store a value in the SP of your app, and it will always be accessable.

Comment: i store it easy from other activity/fragment , but how to get it in a class with no context ?

Comment: You could make the variable in your MainActivity class `public static`.

Answer (score 0):

I sounds like you should pass a `Context` into the constructor of your class, preferably the Application Context to avoid a memory leak, and use it when you need to access the `SharedPreferences`.

Something like this:

```
public class SomeClass{

  private Context con;

  public SomeClass(Context c){

     this.con = c;

  }

  public static int getPreferencedCurrency(){

        SharedPreferences prefs = con.getSharedPreferences(Constants.SHARED_PREFERENCES_NAME,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        return prefs.getInt(Constants.CURRENCY_PREFERRED,0);

    }
}
```

Use the Application Context when initializing an instance of the class:

```
SomeClass sc = new SomeClass(getApplicationContext());
```